# Skipping acquire of configured file '.. doesn't support architecture 'arm64'

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian, repository, raspberry-pi3

whenever I do `sudo apt-get update` this output appear

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'contrib/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'non-free/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'rpi/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'
```

and it's so annoying that there are `>N: Skipping acquire of configured file` line, although these line are not affect the performance, I mean I can still update or upgrade packages or even install packages without problem.

so the question is, how can I remove those `>N: Skipping acquire of configures file` message

Comment: Is this an original 32 bit raspbian, or the 64 bit beta?

Comment: I don't know, how do i check that?

Comment: Type `uname -m` in a shell. If it says something with ARMv7 it is 32 bit, if it says ARMv8 it is 64 bits.

Comment: it says "armv7l" so i think it's 32 bit

Comment: Then it appears you have incorrect and/or broken package sources installed. Check the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`. There should not be anything that says arm64.

Comment: I don't have my RPi ready to check, but the next version of Raspbian will officially be 64 bit, and maybe the errors happen also because the servers are being prepared for the upgrade.

Comment: no, I didn't found anything that says 'arm 64', but on ```/etc/apt/sources.list``` I only found this line ```deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi```

Comment: Hmm... mine is same, and I don't get these errors. I don't know what's wrong there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by entering the following command:

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture arm64
```

I suspect I may have added the `arm64` architecture by mistake at some earlier time. The standard `32-bit` Raspberry Pi OS (aka Raspbian) does not support `64-bit` applications.

Answer (score 1):

Because a repository which defined in your **sources.list** doesn't support one of your **APT::Architectures** config options.
Usually, a software developers in their installation's guides writes a common form of repository specification, like a
`deb uri suite component1 [component2 component3 ... ]`
This is a one-line-style format specification of repository. I assume that your specification looks like:
`deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease`,
where http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian is a **uri**, buster is a **suite**, and InRelease is a **component1**. The `deb uri suite component1` format is the simplest, and it will guarantee that apt-get will work forever with that repository on the most of user's computers. But, there is a little trap: the developers doesn't know in advance which architectures supported on every machine of every user. When a user have architecture, which is not present in repository, he get the **Skipping acquire of configured file '.. doesn't support architecture 'arm64'** error.
An answer in the `man sources.list`:

```
The format for two one-line-style entries using the deb and deb-src types is:
   deb [ option1=value1 option2=value2 ] uri suite [component1] [component2] [...]
   deb-src [ option1=value1 option2=value2 ] uri suite [component1] [component2] [...]
```

, and:

```
Architectures (arch) is an option. If this option isn't set the default is all architectures as defined by the APT::Architectures config option.
```

It means that  architecture **arm64** is also set on your machine, and packages with this architecture requested by your package manager when it is calling that repository. All your APT::Architectures you can see in /etc/apt/apt.conf, or executing in the bash:

```bash
> apt-config dump | grep -F "APT::Architectures" -
```

The correct solution of your issue is to use a repository specification with defined **Architecture** option. If you need the **arm**, not the **arm64**, then specification should be:
`deb [arch=arm] http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease`
With this format the apt package manager will request only packages with  **arm** architecture from the  repository.

Comment: To not mess things up, you should use `apt edit-source file-name.list` to edit repository specification.